# Firebase - Dynamic Links Limit

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I've been trying to do some research into the use of Dynamic Links with Firebase and was curious if anyone knew of any limit on the number of dynamic links we can use. For example, we're looking to generate links server side which is dynamic and will log users into our apps. However, this will go into the 10,000s. so will this be a bit too extreme for Firebase and therefore not a viable solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fine - the limits on FDL will be in terms of how many you can create per second, so as long as you spread the creation out, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

Based on my (short) experience, if using the free plan there is a limit of 100 links per 100 seconds per user, which means if you generate links on the backend (like I do) you are basically limited to creating 1 link per second, which is not much. If you exceed this limit you receive an error like this:

```
429 Too Many Requests
Insufficient tokens for quota 'DefaultQuotaGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service
```

Also a lot of times the Dynamic Links API returns error 503 Service Unavailable when generating links instead of 429, I don't know why but I don't think they have availability issues. It's just kind of confusing.

Here is what I see on my project's quotas page:

```
Default quota. per day  100,000 
Default quota. per 100 seconds  5,000 
Default quota. per 100 seconds per user     100
```

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: Thank you szx, that's also what the official documentation says. But I'm doing some tests and those numbers don't seem to hold really. Can you give any feedback based on your experience ? do those numbers hold for you ?. Thanks in advance.